# Delete the image from imageview onclick deletebutton

Tags: android, image, android-intent, user-interface

I want to delete the image when the user click delete button and replace by next image from the Array.

here i have taken horizontal list view to display images,in each view i have added delete button ,On-click delete button i want to delete the image.

code:

```
private class  Horiadapter extends BaseAdapter {

        public Horiadapter(){
            super();
        }
        private OnClickListener mOnButtonClicked = new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Button bt = (Button) v;

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pressed " + bt.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          
            }
        };


        public int getCount() {
            return dataObjects.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }


        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View viewitems = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.viewitem, null);

            ImageView images=(ImageView)viewitems.findViewById(R.id.image);
            Button button = (Button) viewitems.findViewById(R.id.delbutton);

            button.setOnClickListener(mOnButtonClicked);

            images.setImageResource(imageIds[position]);

            return viewitems;
        }

    };
```

I would really be thankful if anybody could help me.

Comment: What have you tried and what is not working perfectly? If you are specific, help will come.

Comment: @Gogu i have check some answers regarding this...but not suggestable

Comment: on click of delete button just remove that element from array and set adapter.setNotifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: @Priya could you please explain with code..

Answer (score 1):

try putting this in your click handler images.SetVisibility(View.Gone) or images.Visibilty = ViewStates.Gone